# Jersey No serializer found for SingleJust

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, rx-java2, spring-jersey

I am trying to return a `Single.just(..)` from my endpoint.
I have created it using jersey and rx-jersey.
I keep getting this message on my browser:

```
No serializer found for class io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

Here is my code:-

JerseyCOnfig:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(RxJerseyServerFeature.class);
        register(RxJerseyClientFeature.class);
        register(new JacksonJsonProvider(new ObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)));
        register(UserService.class);
    }
}
```

My End point

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @GET
    @Path("/setup/rx")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Single<User> setupRx() {
        return Single.just(new User(29));
    }
}
```

User:-

```
    public class User {

        private Integer age;
//getters and settters
```

Comment: Don't register your own `JacksonJsonProvider`. Use a `ContextResolver`. Or if you are using Spring Boot, just make an `ObjectMapper` `@Bean`

Comment: It still does not work!!! gives me the same error

Comment: Ok!!!..........

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for the jersey service to return any kind of observable. You would use chains of observables to produce concrete files or pages, but not observables.

In your case, the result of the GET method would be `User`, not instructions on how to get `User`.

Comment: I want to create a backend service that fetches data from DB reactively. This is a trivial example but the idea is that the UI based on react will call this backend service to get details

Comment: Whether it is reactive or not, you cannot serve an observable over the internet. At some point, you have to transmit real data values.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion that I caused. Were you able to copy and paste the sample code and get it working?

Comment: Its ok, you don' t need to apologise. No, I was not able to make it work!!!

Comment: @AmarDev Stop using `!!!`. In American culture it's like you are screaming at the person. It's like using all capitals.

Comment: Oh apologies, I did not know. Any ideas about my issue here.